# electron ipcRenderer sync with ipcMain

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, electron, ipc

My problem is when i call ipcMain operation from the renderer process
the renderer thread is stuck untill the ipcMain operation is done(sync instead async)

**Code example**:

Renderer.js

```
export const startCopy = data => {

  // Copy files tree to the drive
  ipcRenderer.send('copy-files', data);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    ipcRenderer.on('copy-files-finished', (event, error) => {

      resolve(error);
    });
  });

}
```

Main.js

```
ipcMain.on('copy-files', (event, data) => {

  const error = copyFiles();

  console.log(error);

  event.sender.send('copy-files-finished', error);
});
```

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes same problem I encountered when I was working on electron problem, So I would like to suggest you one options that I think It is best one from my knowledge

> Do time consuming task or system related task in separate window which
>   is independent from  Main window(Render process) It will never affect
>   your Main window(Render process).

after that send Message to Main window(Render process) in order to Notify and update UI.